# GIT how to set .gitconfig to recognize *.woff files as binary

Tags: git, font-awesome

How to set .gitconfig to recognize *.woff files ?
I try with:

```
*.eot binary
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```

but I've got

> fatal: bad config file line 15 in .git/config

Can you help me, please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a file `.gitattributes` (same location as the .gitignore file in your repository) with your

```
*.eot binary
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```

Please also check [.gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Answer (score 3):

Just add to @uhausbrand answer, to include this missing extension *.otf to `.gitattributes` file. Then the final result will be like this:

```
*.eot binary
*.otf binary
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```